# How can I map this strange @ManyToMany relationship in JPA 2.1?

Tags: java, jpa

I have 2 tables: ANAGRAFICA_COUPON and DETTAGLIO_PDV_ADERENTI_INIZIATIVE with these primary keys

```
ANAGRAFICA_COUPON                 (ID_ANAGRAFICA, COD_CANALE, COD_CAMPAGNA, COD_SEGMENTO)

DETTAGLIO_PDV_ADERENTI_INIZIATIVE (ID_ANAGRAFICA, COD_CANALE, COD_CAMPAGNA, COD_LOCAZIONE)
```

I need to have a List inside class ANAGRAFICA_COUPON, selecting them using a JOIN on ID_ANAGRAFICA, COD_CANALE, COD_CAMPAGNA (which is actually a subset of the 2 primary keys).

How can I map this relationship using JPA entities? It seems to be a @ManyToMany but there's no jointable, so I can't understand how to do it.

Comment: Firstly, I see repetitiveness of fields in your two tables. Following all the steps of normalization of your database schema up to 3NF will clear things. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization .

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have write permissions

Comment: Then, how are you going to create the relationship? Creating a @ManyToMany relationship means that the jpa engine will create a new database table connecting the two entities...